# node.children is not getting rendered in a material nested tree

Tags: angular, angular-material, lazy-loading, nested-lists

I have implemented lazy loading at every node in a material nested tree and for the sake of simplicity, i'm loading the data at every node locally but the aim is to load the data via API. When I toggle the node, its children (node.children) is not getting rendered.

Please find the code below that I have used for lazy loading implementation

TreeComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NestedTreeControl, FlatTreeControl } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { MatTreeNestedDataSource, MatTreeFlatDataSource } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { Region } from 'src/app/tree-node-model';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/services/api.service';

const tempData: Region[] = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "Tamil Nadu",
    children: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Chennai",
        population: 9000000,
        child: true
      }
    ]
  }
];

const stateData: Region[] = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "Tamil Nadu",
    children: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Chennai",
        population: 9000000,
        children: [
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "North Chennai",
            population: 2500000,
            children: [
              {
                name: "Central",
                population: 1000000
              },
              {
                name: "Paris",
                population: 750000
              },
              {
                name: "Ennore",
                population: 750000
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name: "West Chennai",
            population: 3000000,
            children: [
              {
                name: "Anna Nagar",
                population: 750000
              },
              {
                name: "Porur",
                population: 1000000
              },
              {
                name: "Koyambedu",
                population: 550000
              },
              {
                name: "Ashok Nagar",
                population: 300000
              },
              {
                name: "K.K. Nagar",
                population: 400000
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: "South Chennai",
            population: 3500000,
            children: [
              {
                name: "Mylapore",
                population: 950000
              },
              {
                name: "Adyar",
                population: 1350000
              },
              {
                name: "Besant Nagar",
                population: 700000
              },
              {
                name: "Sholinganallur",
                population: 500000
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tree',
  templateUrl: './tree.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tree.component.css']
})
export class TreeComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string = "Tree Lazy Loading Pie Chart testing!";
  dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<Region>();
  treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<Region>(node => node.children);
  treeData: Region[] = [];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.data = tempData;

  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: Region) => (!!node.children && node.children.length > 0) || node.child;

  isLeafNode = (_: number, node: Region) => !node.children || (node.children.length === 0 && !node.child);

  loadChildren(node: Region) {
    console.log("loadchildren function is called");
    this.treeData = this.apiService.getChildrenById(node.id, stateData);
    console.log(this.treeData);
    console.log(this.dataSource.data);
    const newChildren = [...this.treeData];
    node.children = newChildren;
    this.dataSource.data= [...this.dataSource.data];
  }

  
}
```

And the respective template for the tree component

```
<!-- Define the template for the tree node -->
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodeToggle>
    <!-- Render the tree node content -->
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="loadChildren(node)">
      <mat-icon>{{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}</mat-icon>
    </button>
    {{node.name}}
  </mat-tree-node>

  <!-- Render the tree node children recursively -->
  <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
    <div [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
      <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
    </div>
  </mat-nested-tree-node>

  <!-- Render the tree node leaf nodes -->
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: isLeafNode">
    {{node.name}}
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

I did check if I'm getting the correct children data for the current node in `loadChildren()` and that seems to be the case. `dataSource.data` is also updated properly with node data(please do check if necessary) so I'm not sure what am I doing wrong here. I would really appreciate it if someone could point out the obvious, thank you.